# What does "The non-generic type 'System.Web.UI.Pair' cannot be used with type arguments" mean?

Tags: c#, .net, export-to-excel

```
 foreach (Pair<Pair<int, int>, Cell> cell in sheet.Cells)
            {
                dgvCells[cell.Left.Right, cell.Left.Left].Value = cell.Right.Value;
            }
```

I am working on creating a excel file from within .NET, using this [Excel Library](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/)

I am getting the warning mentioned in the title. Any ideas?

Comment: what' the type of dgvCells and it's .Value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for future reference, and understanding, the error message:

The non-generic type '' cannot be used with type arguments

is replaced with some class, indicates that within your code you are attempting to make use of a non-[generic class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in a generic way. More specifically you are using some syntax which is incompatible with that type, in this case the <> generic braces on the type "Pair".

**To typically solve the problem**

- Identify the types use within the file, specifically its use in a generic way. (This should find them: Ctrl + F > "SomeClass<")
- Ensure that the type is as expected (F12 on the type should take you to its declaration)
- If the type is different to the expected type you should make use of a [using alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to point to the correct type [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) i.e.

  ```
  using Pair = Fully.Qualified.Namespace.Of.Pair;
  ```
- If the type is as expected ensure that it is generic, if not you can either modify it to be generic, if you have permission/access to do so, or you could select/create a different type which is more suitable for your purpose.
- Alternativly you could modify your use of the type to be non-generic

Answer (score 2):

It means that `Pair` in the code above is referring to `System.Web.UI.Pair` instead of some other "pair" class such as `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair` (which *is* generic).

Depending on which `Pair` the above code was meant to instantiate, use something like

```
using Pair = MyNamespace.Pair;
```

to resolve the issue (this example assumes you really want to use `MyNamespace.Pair`).

**Update:**

It seems that in your case the exact solution is

```
using Pair = QiHe.CodeLib.Pair;
```

Comment: I got it...it is another class file in the excel library.

Answer (score 0):

Because MSDN provides the Pair definition as:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public sealed class Pair
```

There is not a definition that includes `Pair<T1, T2>`. If there is another Pair class, you need to include that namespace in your 'using' clause.